# Обфускация api-key от firebase

Tags: java, android, безопасность, firebase, key

Каким образом можно обфусцировать api-key от firebase в android приложении на java. Api-ключ лежит в google-services.json.

Я ищу способ сокрыть мой api-ключ от поверхностного реверс-инжиниринга. Думаю достаточно будет что-то простое, в духе разбить ключ на несколько частей и в рантайме динамически собирать из этих частей ключ обратно.

Проблема в том что мой код никак не взаимодействует с этим файлом(не извлекает из этого файла ключ), всем этим занимается библиотека для работы с firebase. Соответственно я не представляю как это можно реализовать.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Не создавайте сами себе проблем, если файл вам не доступен это сделано не просто так. Если бы гугл решил что api-key хранить в google-services.json небезопасно, было бы сделано по другому.

Comment: вообще-то можно динамически заменять ключ. Когда-то использовали такую конструкцию для динамического переключения с базы на базу. Но код нужно искать.... Если у Вас совсем ничего не нагуглитсья я попробую найти, но сначала поищите так.